# serialize() does not work with apostrophe

Tags: php, jquery, serialization

I'm having some trouble with my code below when trying to submit a form dynamically. The serialize() function works great except when there is an apostrophe in a form field.

From the other places I've looked online, it appears serialize() is supposed to take care of that. For some odd reason, it fails on me.

Here is my code:

```
//Submit Edit Facility form data
$("#Facility_Edit").click(function() {  
    var dataString = $("#edit_facility").serialize();

    alert (dataString); //return false;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function() {
          $('#submitresults').html("<div id='message' class='alert-message fade in' data-alert='alert'></div>");
          $('#message').html("<b>Account has been edited successfully!</b>")
          .append("<p>If you would like to make more changes, please do so below. Otherwise, please click <a href='facility.php?facility_id=<?php echo $facility_id;?>'>here to view the account.</p>")
          .hide()
          .fadeIn(1500, function() {
            $('#message').prepend("<a class='close' href='#'>&times;</a>");
            setTimeout('window.location="facility.php?facility_id=<?php echo $facility_id;?>&action=edit"', 3000)
          });
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

This is the output I receive with an apostrophe:

```
Facility_Name=Coeur+d'Alene+Homes+&Facility_Type=Assisted+Living+Facility&
Facility_Address=624+W+Harrison&Facility_Beds=&Facility_City=Coeur+d'Alene&
Facility_State=ID&Facility_Zip=83814&Facility_OC=Tambra&Facility_Phone=&Facility_HCC=&
Facility_Fax=&Facility_Team=CDA&Facility_DC=&facility_facilitypreference_status=&
Facility_ID=1305&Submit_Type=editfacility
```

Notice, when the apostrophe's are removed, the code works great and submits properly. How can I fix this?

**EDIT: Added PHP side code**

```
$facility_name = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['Facility_Name']));               
$facility_type = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['Facility_Type']));
$facility_address = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['Facility_Address']));         
$facility_zip = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['Facility_Zip']));
$facility_oc = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['Facility_OC']));               
$facility_hcc = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['Facility_HCC']));
$facility_phone = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['Facility_Phone']));             
$facility_beds = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['Facility_Beds']));
$facility_fax = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['Facility_Fax']));             
$facility_dc = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['Facility_DC']));
```

I've also tried:

```
$facility_name = htmlspecialchars(addslashes(trim($_POST['Facility_Name'])));               
$facility_type = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['Facility_Type']));
$facility_address = htmlspecialchars(addslashes(trim($_POST['Facility_Address'])));
```

Comment: Don't get it. The post data string is still valid with apostrophe right?

Comment: That's what I don't understand. I've added some php to my original post.

Answer (score 1):

```
var dataString = $("#edit_facility").serialize().replace(/\'/g,'\\\'');
```

or better, use one of the various javascript "addslashes" function out there.

however, what happens when if you do

```
$_POST = array_map('addslashes', $_POST);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried use [encodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)? :

```
var dataString = encodeURI($("#edit_facility").serialize());
```

If that doesn't works, so take no risks: Try with [htmlspecialchars](http://phpjs.org/functions/htmlspecialchars:426).

```
var dataString = htmlspecialchars($("#edit_facility").serialize() , 'ENT_QUOTES')
```

And in your php make:

```
$facility_name = trim($_POST['Facility_Name']));
```

I hope with that you can solve your problem.

**EDIT:**

I was made a test with two files:

**serialize.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="post">
</div>
<form name="form1" id="form1" action="#">
    <p><input type="text" id="Facility_Name" name="Facility_Name" value="Coeur d'Alene Homes"/>
    <p><input type="text" id="Facility_Type" name="Facility_Type" value="Assisted Living Facility"/>
    <p><input type="text" id="Facility_Address" name="Facility_Address" value="624 W Harrison"/>

    <p><button type="button" id="send">Send</button>
</form>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#send').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "serialize1.php",
                data: $('#form1').serialize(),
                success: function(sData) {
                    $('#post').html(sData);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**serialize1.php**

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

And in serialize1.php in chrome, firefox and IE I get:

```
array(3) {
  ["Facility_Name"]=>
  string(19) "Coeur d'Alene Homes"
  ["Facility_Type"]=>
  string(24) "Assisted Living Facility"
  ["Facility_Address"]=>
  string(14) "624 W Harrison"
}
```

In order to help you I would appreciate give to me more information.

Comment: encodeURI specifically does not encode or escape single quotes.

Comment: When I do that, the data simply gets passed to the URL and nothing happens: `facility.php?Facility_Name=Coeur+d%27Alene+Homes+&Facility_Type=Assisted+Living+Facility&Facility_Address=624+W+Harrison&Facility_Beds=&Facility_City=Coeur+d%27Alene&Facility_State=ID&Facility_Zip=83814&Facility_OC=Tambra&Facility_Phone=&Facility_HCC=&Facility_Fax=&Facility_Team=CDA&Facility_DC=&facility_facilitypreference_status=&Facility_ID=1305&Submit_Type=editfacility&submit=Submit+Changes`

Comment: Your answer is correct, Galled. It appears there is an error in my php that's causing it to not work correctly. Thanks!

Comment: @mraliks I would appreciate that you marks my answer as correct. :D

Answer (score 0):

Okay, if you are using PHP, I would suggest that you use PDO. Prepared statements escape everything by default and no need for extra coding. eg.

PHP SIDE CODE

```
$facility_name = $_POST['Facility_Name'];
$Insert = $pdo-Prepare("Insert into table (`id`, `facility_name `) VALUES (NULL,:facility_name )");
$Insert->bindParam(':facility_name ',$facility_name);
$insert->execute();
```

That's about it. Nothing to IT.

Answer (score 0):

Year 2017, and I find it hard to believe this problem is still around.

For starters, let me brief you on how serialize works. Here is an example:

a:6:{i:0;s:27:"I wouldnrrt mind, it is her";i:1;s:14:"his own choice";i:2;s:27:"I wouldnrrt mind as long he";i:3;s:52:"her is ready to do anything to fight it with my help"

Now, a:6 tells you that there are six elements in the serialized array. After that, i:0, means this is the first element. AND NOW you see the problem, s:27 tells that the string has 27 characters. But I did notice that when there is a --> ' <--- in the string, it counts not 1 but 2 characters. This means that serialize is NOT failing. There are 27 characters in the string when it goes to the database. But the database sees \' and removes the \ leaving only the '. When this data goes back to PHP and it tries to unserialize, it sees s:27, but a string with 26 characters. And that's when the problem starts.

My solution was fixing the string before unserializing it:

$question_level['answers1'] = str_replace('\'', '\\'', $question_level['answers1']);